# OpenCV How to use ::FileStorage or Boost to save pointers?

Tags: c++, opencv, boost

I am currently working on a project in which i have a huge array, where each element is composed of a ::Mat, a ::Point2d, and some other primitives and pointers. Posteriorly, I create multiple objects, which point to some of the locations in this big array. This means each of these objects is composed of a vector of pointers. I am trying to save my big model on disk but unfortunatelly was not successful yet.

I tried two things:

1. Use ::FileStorage to accomplish the mission, however, as soon as a pointer emerges, nothing works anymore. Since my structure is roughly composed of just pointers, this has not helped.
2. The other way i found, which copes with pointers very wel, was boost. However, none of the OpenCV objects has a serialize routine, required to boost::serialize it.

Has someone done something alike before? Thanks for your help!

Comment: research term - persistent storage.  You need to store what is pointed at, because the pointers you store will not be valid after the restart / reload.

Comment: Yes, I know that. boost saves the object once and then saves relationships of the pointers to the object, generating the initial structure after loading. For FileStorage, i haven't found something close to it. Thanks for your reply :)